# How to extract parts of a HDF5 array matrix and its' corresponding row attribute

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, hdf5

I'm working with a gene dataset that is originally stored as a HDF5 format. It has a format similar to the below (I have added some arbitrary numbers and genes to illustrate how it looks like). So it has genes as a row attribute and a main numpy matrix containing the numerical data. The columns would represent repeats, i.e. different cells.

I have another file that contains a list of genes I'm interested in (below represented by my_gene_list as an example). What I would like to do is extract the numerical data for the genes I'm interested in ***as well as the corresponding gene***, either as a structured array or pandas DataFrame (i.e. having the gene as an index).

```
  Gene                                      ...
  RP11-.3     1   2   3   0   7   0   0   0 ...
  FAM138A     2   0   1   0   6   0   0   0 ...
  CACNA1C     3   0   6   0   5   0   0   0 ...
  RP11-.7     4   0   8   0   4   0   0   0 ...
  RP11-.8     5   0   9   0   3   0   0   0 ...
  FO538.2     6   0   2   0   2   0   0   0 ...
  AP006.2     7   0   0   0   1   0   0   0 ...
    ...         ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...

my_gene_list=['CACNA1C', 'RP11-.7']
```

Using a for loop, I am able to extract the numerical data for each gene in my list. I know this works as I tried printing both the gene and the corresponding array.

```
for element in my_gene_list:
    set[set.ra.Gene==element] # set is the name of the whole dataset
```

However, for obvious reasons, I also want to know which row belongs to which gene, and this is where I am stuck. I don't know how to store the actual outputs as I would like, shown underneath. This applies both for the array itself and the corresponding gene name.

```
FAM138A     2   0   1   0   6   0   0   0 ...
RP11-.7     4   0   8   0   4   0   0   0 ...
```

I have been exploring how to do it in completely separate steps, using lists, dictionaries, repeatedly appending to a dataframe, but I would like a method that guarantees that the order is maintained (both gene-array and the columns within the array itself.

I tried appending the output array after my for loop as a list and then making an array out of the list using 'np.asarray', but for some reason I have yet to understand, the result was a 3-dimensional array and I'm at the moment not proficient enough in numpy (or Python for that matter) to reshape it into a 2d array and guarantee that the order isn't messed up. Even if I do it in this manner, I still don't have the gene names. I guess I could do the same thing for them, then create a pandas DataFrame out of the numerical data and add the gene names to the same DataFrame. Would the order in this case be maintained throughout?

**To reiterate, the above code is only an example, the dataset I am using contains around 28 000 genes and my list has around 50, which is why I am inquiring on how to do this.**

I hope my question is clear. I've done my best to explain it properly. If something is unclear, please let me know. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can you show the code that you use to load the data?

Comment: One thing that's confusing is whether you loaded the data as numpy arrays via `h5py`, or as pandas dataset (with its `pytables').  Once loaded it really doesn't matter whether the data came from a HDF5 file or not.

Comment: I'm using loompy to load the data.

Comment: Never heard of it, and I don't see any relevant tags.

Comment: @hpaulj If you glance at the description at loompy.org, you'll get an idea of it. I didn't include it because it's new and designed for gene datasets in particular, so I figured that most people  wouldn't have heard of it. But as far as I know, the files are HDF5, which is why I only included that.

Comment: It might to loop with `for i, element in enumerate(...):`  That way you can keep track of which `element` number you are matching.